# Inconsistent English-International Keyboard Behavior

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, language, windows-10-v1903, international

So far every Q&A I've found on any forum is either how to turn on ENG-INTL or turn it off because of the tendency of ' or " and other modifier keys to simply input two of themselves, but I've seen a completely different issue.

Sometimes I can use the advertised shortcut of pressing ['] followed by [a] and get á. Most times, however, pressing ['] just gives me two single-quotes. The behavior is inconsistent (or at least dependent upon factors I cannot identify), and I've seen it happen on two different installations of Windows 10 where I've enabled the US-INTL keyboard.

- My input options are ENG-US and ENG-INTL
- Keyboard is a rather basic AZIO mechanical, no macros have ever been configured or used
- Preferred/installed language is only English (United States)
- Windows is v10 Pro 1903, build 18362.836

I'm genuinely curious how I can get the modifiers to work for diacritics and accents consistently, on account I regularly use them and having to memorize every last alt-code (Alt-0233 = á) is not terribly practical.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, support for accents and other diacritics is very limited on the 'US-International' layout.

You can type letters like à, á, è, é, but not ź, š, etc.

I use [UltimateKEYS](https://pieter-degroote.github.io/UltimateKEYS/) as an alternative (derived from [EurKEY](https://eurkey.steffen.bruentjen.eu/)), as it provides many more symbols, and does not bother you with broken quotation marks (and apostrophe).

See also this [list of alternatives](https://pieter-degroote.github.io/list-keyboard-layouts.html) on my site.

Just be sure **not** to put any other character in your system passwords than 'Basic Latin' (codes 32 to 126) as the login screen might only show US QWERTY, preventing you from typing any special Unicode character (-> **account lockout**).

*Please note that I am the creator of UltimateKEYS.*

Comment: Please [edit] your answer and disclose your affiliation, as you are the author of UltimateKEYS.